# How can I check if my subject raises an exception?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I'm currently creating an object in `subject` and need to test if this raises an exception. The following code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
describe MyClass do
  describe '#initialize' do
    subject { MyClass.new }

    it { is_expected.not_to raise_error(Some::Error) }
  end
end
```

I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way. What is the preferred way to set the `subject` to a new object, without creating the object twice?

---

**Update**

My problem was two-fold. Firstly, this syntax does not work:

```
it { is_expected.not_to raise_error }
```

Using `expect` inside an `it` block does, however (as pointed out by Jimmy Cuadra):

```
it 'does not raise an error' do
  expect { subject }.not_to raise_error
end
```

I am not well enough acquainted with RSpec to tell you why this is.

Secondly, since [RSpec 3.0.0.beta1](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/releases/tag/v3.0.0.beta1), it is longer possible to use `raise_error` with a specific error class. The following, therefore, is invalid:

```
expect { subject }.to raise_error(Some::Error)
```

For more information, see

- [Rspec 3.0.0.beta1 changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/releases/tag/v3.0.0.beta1)
- [Consider deprecating `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` #231](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/231)
- [Remove expect {}.not_to raise_error(SomeSpecificClass) #294](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/294)

Comment: You have an [implicit subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject), so you don't need `subject { MyClass.new }`.

Comment: Handy to know, @ArupRakshit! Although the constructor in my simplified example did not take arguments, though, the one in my actual class does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to test if instantiating a class causes an exception. You would just do this:

```
describe MyClass do
  it "doesn't raise an exception when instantiated" do
    expect { subject }.not_to raise_error
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it is indeed the answer to my question. I've updated the question in case others have similar issues, as there was another issue.

Comment: The key here is you need to put the `subject` inside of an `expect` block. You can't use `it 
 { is_expected.not_to raise_error }` and you can use `expect { subject.not_to raise_error }`. You need to use `expect { subject }.not_to raise_error`. Cheers for the answer here.

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do that through `is_expected` syntax is to wrap your subject value by a Proc, like the following example:

```
describe MyClass do
  describe '#initialize' do
    subject { -> { MyClass.new } }
    it      { is_expected.not_to raise_error(Some::Error) }
  end
end
```

This way is more accurate, because sometimes your use case is to expect that specific kinds of exceptions should not be thrown (while others are allowed to be thrown). This approach will cover such use cases.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just make sure you RSpec version supports `is_expected` method.

Comment: Looks like it just checks if a Proc object raises an exception 

Comment: @OlegAfanasyev Yes. Basically `raise_error` will internally invoke `.call` on the `Proc` stored/returned by the `subject`.

Comment: @leandroico, I did not find any `.call` invocations in the source code nor that it would make any sense to make a special case for subjects evaluating to procs because a subject is already wrapped in a `expect {}` block and is not invoked until test runtime.

Comment: @OlegAfanasyev I believe this Proc-based behavior comes from `raise_error` and not something else.

Comment: @leandroico, I found it [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb#L52), thanks!

It's worth mentioning that your solution works only for `expect()` without block, i.e. `expect {}` won't call the initial proc.

Comment: @OlegAfanasyev The thing is that the whole original comment of mine and the subsequent minor comments that follow are actually around the `is_expected` method.

Comment: **This is *not* "the right way to do it".** This messes up non-raise assertions. The right way to do it is to put the `subject` into its own `block`, like `expect { subject }.not_to raise_error`. See @Jimmy Cuadra's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640639/293280

Comment: This is officially deprecated on rspec-expectations v3.11.0 (2022-02-09). See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/main/Changelog.md#3110--2022-02-09 and https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/1139